# sum when join repeating lines (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query results as follow:

```
SELECT ... ON CIA_factbook_dataset.my_name = World_Bank_dataset.my_name ...

+----------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
| my_name        | Year | CIA_name    | World_Bank_name | CIA_GDP | WB_GDP |
+----------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
| United Kingdom | 2010 | UK          | United Kingdom  | 2850    | 2800   |
| United Kingdom | 2010 | UK          | Channel Islands | 2850    |   11   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 | CYPRUS TURK | CYPRUS TURK     |   22    |   22   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 | CYPRUS TURK | CYPRUS GRK      |   22    |   33   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 | CYPRUS GRK  | CYPRUS TURK     |   33    |   22   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 | CYPRUS GRK  | CYPRUS GRK      |   33    |   33   |
+----------------+------+-------------+-----------------+---------+--------+
```

I need to calculate the sum of the sub-country data, But if I'm using just `GROUP BY my_name,year`, it calculates the sum of the same number few times.

The final result should be:

```
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
| my_name        | Year | CIA_GDP | WB_GDP |
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
| United Kingdom | 2010 | 2850    | 2811   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 |   55    |   55   |
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
```

Instead of:

```
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
| my_name        | Year | CIA_GDP | WB_GDP |
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
| United Kingdom | 2010 | 5700    | 2811   |
| Cyprus         | 2010 |  110    |  110   |
+----------------+------+---------+--------+
```

How to achieve that?
Any better way than to use `SUM(distinct CIA_GDP),SUM(distinct WB_GDP)`?
(Theoretically, the GDP of turkish cyprus and greek cyprus might be the same)

Comment: Wait, Why is `United Kingdom(CIA_GDP)` the `MAX()` and `Cyprus(CIA_GDP)` the `SUM()` in your desired output ?

Comment: who talked about MAX ?!

Comment: Ok, I got it, my bad, 2min

Comment: (CIA consider the UK as one country, WorldBank as two)

Comment: answer updated ;)

Comment: Question, how do you end up with those desired results? could you please explain how and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I'm assuming `my_name`, `Year` is unique in both tables.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70f44/29)

```
SELECT t1.my_name, t1.YEAR, SUM_CIA_GDP, SUM_WB_GDP
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT my_name, YEAR, SUM(CIA_GDP) AS SUM_CIA_GDP
    FROM t
    GROUP BY my_name, YEAR, WB_GDP
    ) t1
JOIN (   
    SELECT DISTINCT my_name, YEAR, SUM(WB_GDP) AS SUM_WB_GDP
    FROM t
    GROUP BY my_name, YEAR, CIA_GDP
    ) t2 
    ON t1.my_name = t2.my_name 
        AND t1.YEAR = t2.YEAR
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70f44/29/0)**:

```
|        my_name | YEAR | SUM_CIA_GDP | SUM_WB_GDP |
|----------------|------|-------------|------------|
|         Cyprus | 2010 |          55 |         55 |
| United Kingdom | 2010 |        2850 |       2811 |
```

Comment: no space between `SUM` and `(` ; & ERROR : `Column 'my_name' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: excellent! just the `GROUP BY` should not contain `CIA_name / World_Bank_name`

Comment: BTW, avoid JOIN on subquery when you can, that's not efficient for the DB engine and if you got more row it'll start to be slower

Comment: Correct, `JOIN` on subquery would lead to performance issue. The answer here would be for your understanding based on the basic requirement. Would need to further revise with more complicated situation. Btw, I've edited the answer to correct the typos and make it more simple.

Comment: I take the liberty to correct the two mistakes left, if you don't mind ;) (cf error in : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70f44/31 ) ;; you need the `group by`s done by `CIA_GDP` | `WB_GDP` and DISTINCT (or you'll have SUM of duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70f44/13)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`my_name` varchar(14), `Year` int, `CIA_name` varchar(11), `World_Bank_name` varchar(15), `CIA_GDP` int, `WB_GDP` int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`my_name`, `Year`, `CIA_name`, `World_Bank_name`, `CIA_GDP`, `WB_GDP`)
VALUES
    ('United Kingdom', 2010, 'UK', 'United Kingdom', 2850, 2800),
    ('United Kingdom', 2010, 'UK', 'Channel Islands', 2850, 11),
    ('Cyprus', 2010, 'CYPRUS TURK', 'CYPRUS TURK', 22, 22),
    ('Cyprus', 2010, 'CYPRUS TURK', 'CYPRUS GRK', 22, 33),
    ('Cyprus', 2010, 'CYPRUS GRK', 'CYPRUS TURK', 33, 22),
    ('Cyprus', 2010, 'CYPRUS GRK', 'CYPRUS GRK', 33, 33)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT my_name, Year, SUM(CIA_GDP), WB_GDP
FROM (
  SELECT my_name, Year, CIA_GDP, SUM(WB_GDP) WB_GDP
  FROM t
  GROUP BY my_name, Year, CIA_GDP
  ) t1
GROUP BY my_name, Year, WB_GDP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70f44/13/0)**:

```
|        my_name | Year | SUM(CIA_GDP) | WB_GDP |
|----------------|------|--------------|--------|
|         Cyprus | 2010 |           55 |     55 |
| United Kingdom | 2010 |         2850 |   2811 |
```

Comment: for Cyprus (in the example), I need the SUM of both `CIA_GDP , WB_GDP`

Comment: @Dani-Br and how you know you make a SUM for Cyprus and not for UK ? Why ?

Comment: nice! but the SUM(WB_GDP) for Cyprus should be 55. not 110.

Comment: @Dani-Br u_u ok, need to sleep, wrong copy / past, 2s and it's good

Comment: thanks for your time. For now, I choose the @ydoow's solution, because the table contains fields from few datasets, so ydoow's code will be more clear.

Comment: @Dani-Br I'm again the twice read of the table with a Join on sub-Q; But if you find it more clear, why not, just careful if your dataset grow a bit ;)